# Get a parallel line

Tags: geometry

I have a line represented by two points (A and B) and another point (C) which does not belongs to this line. How can I get start and end points of a parallel line which contains the given point (C)?

EDIT

I have swift class which represents Line of eyes on the picture.

```
var eyesLine = Line(start: rightEye, end: leftEye)
```

where rightEye and leftEye are CGPoint instances;

I want to get line, which represents mouth. From CIDetector I receive center of mouth. Assume, that angle of mouth is the same as eyes, I want to get line, parallel to eyes.

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understood your question. Have I tried what?

Comment: `D = C + B - A`

Comment: Tried code anything?

Comment: @VladHatko I think he was asking "have you tried literally anything", since it seems likely that you'd be successful if you had.

Comment: yes. why do you ask?

Comment: do you found my question too easy? if so, why you don't provide any helping solution?

Comment: You should post your code so we could help you :)

Comment: I don't understand how it works that way, but ok.

Comment: @RCaetano Is it better now? I don't know, how this additional info may help

Comment: In StackOverflow you should provide your code so others can help you. I think it is easy to understand that it is not fair to us to help someone that just have a question and did not even tried to code anything (or at least did some research or effort). Btw, that's not your case ;)

Comment: Sneftel approach is the simplest and the most effective one.

Comment: Did my answer or @Sneftel answer helped you?

Comment: actually no; I've managed to solve it another way

Comment: Nice! But maybe you should post your solution as na answer so other people in the same situation can understand how to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line equation is `y = mx + b`. So if you want a parallel line you should have a line with the same slope (`m`) but taking into account the point you require (C).

The following formula is also true: `m = (y_B - y_A) / (x_B - x_A)`

So basically you need to solve the following equation with your point:

`b = y_C - ((y_B - y_A) / (x_B - x_A)) * x_C`

Then you just need to compute another `y` coordinate of your choice by changing the values of `x` (because C is already one point of the new line):

`y_D = ((y_B - y_A) / (x_B - x_A)) * x_D + (y_C - ((y_B - y_A) / (x_B - x_A)) * x_C)`

To simplify even more your task you can assume that `x_D = 0` (example) and then you will have only to compute:

`y_D = y_C - ((y_B - y_A) / (x_B - x_A)) * x_C`

Your final points will have `(x_C, y_C)` and `(0, y_D)` coordinates.

**Note:**

At the start of your script you should also check if `x_A = x_B`. If that is true then your final points will have `(x_C, y_C)` and `(x_C, y_D)` coordinates, where `y_D` can be any value except `y_C`.

HTH ;)

Comment: What if line is vertical? School line equation is not fully suitable for computer geometry.

Comment: Added that exception @MBo ;)